# MongoDB WiredTiger cache contents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, wiredtiger

I'm running MongoDB 3.4.7 cluster (primary + 2 secondaries). Primary's cache usage is 95%, and I try to figure out what the cache contains.

I ran collStats for all collections (±18,000) and summarized the "bytes currently in the cache" metric. The total is ±16GB, which is only about half of the cache size (which is 30GB).

When running db.serverStatus(), there seems to be two relevant metrics:

```
"bytes belonging to page images in the cache" : 15933358790, // ±16GB
"bytes not belonging to page images in the cache" : 14141393512, // ±14GB
```

The first one might explain the 16GB summary of the collection cache, however I wonder what the second metric means - what else is MongoDB / WiredTiger store in the cache, and how can I break it down?

Any ideas?